# Cold/cool design in home decor

Tags: word-usage

In my mother tongue, the word "cold/cool" is used to denote a style of design which is not "warm" (cozy, intimate) but rather alienated and modernist, (e.g. using materials such as glass and concrete sharp lines etc.)

Can you do the same in English? Or is there a different word for it? How can you distinguish this use from cool in the sense of 'hip'?

Comment: It's absolutely, precisely, the same in English.  And indeed, the concept originates in English. {Err, after the French of course.} (SImply check a dictionary for this one?)

Comment: Regarding "how can you distinguish".  It's utterly, overwhelmingly, normal and commonplace in English that words have more than one meaning, or more than one slight variety of meaning.  You distinguish shades of meaning by context.  I have literally heard an architect say "do you mean cool as in 'jazz' or cool as in 'Scandinavian' " - it's, to repeat, just overwhelmingly normal in English that words have a variety of different meanings or shades of meaning.

Comment: The problem is that often when people talk about 'cool design' they mean 'trendy design', which is a very different thing...

Comment: Not in my experience. When art directors, designers etc say "cool" they usually mean "restrained, cold-hearted, Scandinavian": literally precisely what you are describing.  What you describe as a "problem" is just overwhelmingly the norm in English.  I can utterly, absolutely, **totally assure you** that "cool" is used, in precisely the sense you mean, by designers, art directors, myself, and zillions of others.

Comment: OK, cool then ;)

Comment: @Joe Blow "cold-hearted?" Why does sleek, minimalist, uncluttered, elegant, easy to take care of have to be cold-hearted?

Comment: hi @ab2 - was just one in a list of purely example adjectives; nothing to be worried about.  if you choose "elegant", God bless.  this is not a design site, it's an English site discussing words, cheers.

Answer (score 1):

I can think of a few words that might come close.

**Spartan**: (*often not capitalized*) marked by simplicity, frugality, or avoidance of luxury and comfort  (from [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/Spartan))

**Austere** markedly simple or unadorned   ([Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/austere))

However, as you see in the definitions, this carries more of a sense of a lack of decoration, so possibly not exactly what you are looking for.  But here, *context is everything*.  Consider:

> From your personality, I expected your home to be very warm and vibrant.  I am somewhat to surprised by your austere style.

Comment: Indeed, if you're just looking for synonyms, glance in a thesaurus for 15 or so.

Comment: I guess, the OP's concern is along the lines: "In English can the word 'cool' be used to mean Scandinavian/restrained/cold-hearted, as opposed to the meaning hip/jazz."  (Answer - very much so, that's the original meaning.  The "hip" or "good" or "no worries" meaning just came along later.)